# App is crashing when you press a button

Tags: java, android

When I press the button the app just crashes (here is the xml file to this)

```
<Button
    android:text="Beginn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/startButton"
    android:onClick="getJson"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

And the code that runs when I press the button.

```
public void getJson(){
    editSummoner =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSummoner);
    if (editSummoner.getText().length() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Please enter a summoner name",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (editSummoner.getText().length() >= 1) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Summoner name is " + editSummoner.getText().toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Any suggestion are welcome, I looked through all the other code and didn't find any misstake. Also the app works when this part of the code is deleted but then the button doesn't work.

Crash report (Android monitor):

```
11-15 20:56:20.137 29501-29501/com.example.user.lolstats E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.user.lolstats, PID: 29501
                                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method getJson(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'startButton'
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5702)
                                                                           at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10888)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22541)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Could you please submit your crash report from your console ?

Comment: Add the code for when the button is clicked as well

Comment: It says "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method getJson(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class" Are your button and getJson method in the same activity?

Comment: the second code  (public void getJson()) is the code

Comment: they are in the same activity but at the xml code android:onClick="getJson"

Comment: is marked and it's written it has and incorrect signature

Comment: Read the error, it requires a method with the signature indicated in the log: `getJson(View)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expecting the method `getJson(View)` with a `View` as parameter, you defined a method `getJson()` with no parameters.

Comment: why do I need (View view) as parameter and what does do?

Comment: @motschel123 that's indicated quite clearly in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You must give View parameter to your method.
Change your method to this:

```
public void getJson(View v){
    editSummoner =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSummoner);
    if (editSummoner.getText().length() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Please enter a summoner name",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (editSummoner.getText().length() >= 1) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Summoner name is " + editSummoner.getText().toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try the other way around.

Delete the onClick row from your xml file. And glue together the button with the method programmatically:

In your onCreate method:

```
Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getJson(); // or you can write here the actual code.
    }
});
```